# Enumerating clients of a 389/Fedora Directory server

Tags: linux, directory, ldap, fedora

I have a Fedora Directory server that I need to shut down.  In order to do so, I need to find a list of all clients currently authenticating to this server.  Not being familiar with Fedora/389 Directory, I was wondering if there's an easy way to do that?  My best option at this point seems to be to comb through the log files.

Answer (score 1):

An LDAP-compliant server should send the [unsolicited notification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511#section-4.4) to clients about events transpiring between the client and server. The notification contains information that the client can use to take an action. Therefore, properly coded clients should not care about the server being shutdown. Clients that do not support the unsolicited notification should have that support added.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Programming Practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)

Comment: This particular directory server was put in place by the previous regime, and was never completed.  That being the case, I'm guessing it's probably not properly coded.  Only a handful of hosts within the environment access it.  There is no secondary LDAP server for failover.  We're looking at a new LDAP solution, but before we get there, I want to decommission the existing one since it is only causing confusion.  I suppose if the client automatically falls back to local authentication, that would be okay.  However, I'm not sure if this would happen.

Comment: If it's helpful for anyone else -- I've been combing through the log files both by hand, and using logconv.pl, to try to determine which users and hosts are accessing this 'rogue' LDAP server.  That seems to be giving me the information I need.